# Replace certain characters in stream

Tags: python, stream

I have a method (a .yml parser) that takes an input stream as input.  The problem is that it throws errors when it encounters certain characters in certain places e.g. `%`.

What I would like to do is take the stream, replace all of the `%` with a place holder, and then pass it to the parser.

This is what I have (which doesn't work with the current input):

```
    stream = open('file.yml', 'r')
    dict = yaml.safe_load(stream)
```

But what I think I need is something like:

```
    stream = open('file.yml', 'r')
    temp_string = stringFromString(stream)     #convert stream to string
    temp_string.replace('%', '_PLACEHOLDER_')  #replace with place holder
    stream = streamFromString(temp_String)     #conver back to stream
    dict = yaml.safe_load(stream)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: Apparently the original answer here no longer appears to work, and the library now requires a file-like object.

Given that, it becomes a little more awkward. You could write your own wrapper that acts in a file-like way (the basis for this would probably be [`io.TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.TextIOBase)) and does the replacement in a buffer, but if you are willing to sacrifice laziness, the easiest solution is roughly what was originally suggested in the question: do the replacement in memory.

The solution for turning a string into a file-like object is [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.StringIO).

---

Old answer:

A good way of doing this would be to write a generator, that way it remains lazy (the whole file doesn't need to be read in at once):

```
def replace_iter(iterable, search, replace):
    for value in iterable:
        value.replace(search, replace)
        yield value

with open("file.yml", "r") as file:
    iterable = replace_iter(file, "%", "_PLACEHOLDER")
    dictionary = yaml.safe_load(iterable)
```

Note the use of the `with` statement to open the file - this is the best way to open files in Python, as it ensures files get closed properly, even when exceptions occur.

Also note that `dict` is a poor variable name, as it will smash the built in `dict()` and stop you from using it.

Do note that your `stringFromStream()` function is essentially `file.read()`, and `steamFromString()` is `data.splitlines()`. What you are calling a 'stream' is actually just an iterator over strings (the lines of the file).

Comment: Ah okay.  I guess my understanding of streams was sub-par.  Thanks for the quick response and +1 for `with`

Comment: The following example fails with AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this somewhere and keep finding this answer when searching for the original source. So maybe this is useful.

Some random non-comformant YAML file with `%`.

```
a:
  b:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3%
  - 4
```

A replace on read drop-in for `open("file.yml", "r")` is:

```
from yaml import safe_load_all

class ReplacePc():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.fn = filename
        self.buffer = ''

    def __enter__(self):
        self.fh = open(self.fn, 'r')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, _type, _value, _tb):
        self.fh.close()

    def read(self, size):
        eof = False
        while self.fn is not None and not eof and len(self.buffer) < size:
            line = self.fh.readline()
            if line == '':
                eof = True
            self.buffer += line.replace('%', '_PC_')
        if len(self.buffer) > size:
            chunk = self.buffer[:size]
            self.buffer = self.buffer[size:]
        else:
            chunk = self.buffer
            self.buffer = ''
        return chunk

with ReplacePc('ex/file_with_pc.yaml') as f:
    for data in safe_load_all(f):
        print(data)
```