# How to pre-process a yaml file in python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, generator

Background is that I have several hundred Yaml files that are configuration files to a system.  I want to analyse them as a whole looking for issues in their config.

So I need to pre-process each files just like this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401062/replace-certain-characters-in-stream) to remove some illegal characters prior to doing some stuff with them. However I am a python newbie and can not the generators solution proposed to work. The real files should not be modified if possible.  I am using python 3.4.

My main problem is that the iterator function does not get called which makes me think I am not accessing the iterator behaviour correctly.

Essentially I have a file processing function that processes all of the files in a directory as follows:

```
with open(os.path.join(myDir, fileName), 'r') as inputFile:
    print("about to call replace_iter")
    iterable = replace_iter(inputFile, "push", "force")
    print("about to call yaml.safe_load()")
    dataMap = yaml.safe_load(iterable)
    print("about to process my data map")
    type = dataMap['type']
    # process the dataMap ites ...
    print("done")
```

And I have a function defined at the top of my file as follows

```
def replace_iter(iterable, search, replace):
    print("replace_iter called")
    for value in iterable:
        yield value.replace(search, replace)
```

This gives an output like this skipping the call to the generator function so it suggests that I am not accessing the iterator functionality correctly.

```
about to call replace_iter
about to call yaml.safe_load()
```

Comment: `value.replace` does not modify `value`, it returns a new object, which you can then `yield`.

Comment: Please do not concatenate dir and file that way. Also, `file` is a built-in function, you should not use it as a variable name. Instead: `with open(os.path.join(myDir, fileName)) as input_file:`

Comment: Does the code get as far as `yaml.safe_load(iterable)`? What about the line before?

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect Hai's suggested improvements.

Comment: @PeterWood as you can see from the my updates it gets to the yaml.safe_load() but it has not actually called the replace_iter function otherwise we would see its debug print line.

Comment: Do you catch exceptions anywhere? Maybe it's failing and you're silencing it with an `except:`.

Comment: No I don't handle exceptons in the code.

Comment: Do you ever get to `print("about to process my data map")`?

Comment: Nope, the yaml.safe_load throws an exception as one of the yaml fields is asterisk.asterisk which is an alias in modern yaml and the very string I want to replace.

Answer (score 2):

[`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) doesn't modify the string, but returns the modified value:

> `str.replace(old, new[, count])`
>   Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

You need to yield the return value instead.

```
def replace_iter(iterable, search, replace):
    for value in iterable:
        yield value.replace(search, replace)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't think I have got to that problem just yet though.  It seems to me that the replace_iter function is not getting called as I get nothing if I put some debug print statements in there.